# Read logs of a Storage trigger cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, python-3.7, google-cloud-logging

I need to read the status of a storage trigger cloud function, the last line of the log

> 2021-03-09 15:47:42.908 IST function_name 6cymbohrrv6g Function execution took 11 ms, finished with status: 'ok'

This way I can determine if the function execution was a success or not.

I tried reading the logs using the below script, but it displays all the logs.

```
    logging_client = logging.Client()
    for entry in logging_client.list_entries():
         timestamp = entry.timestamp.isoformat()
         print("* {}: {}".format(timestamp, entry.payload))
```

Is there some way I can limit the logs to the current execution? Can I read the last log which displays the status of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use and advanced filter in your [`logging_client.list_entries()` method](https://googleapis.dev/python/logging/latest/client.html#google.cloud.logging_v2.client.Client.list_entries). The official documentation of the Python client library for Stackdriver Logging admits this parameter.

> filter (str) – a filter expression. See https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced_filters

For example:

```
from google.cloud import logging

logging_client = logging.Client()
f = 'resource.type="cloud_function" AND resource.labels.function_name="yourFunctionName" AND textPayload:"Function execution took"'
for entry in logging_client.list_entries(filter_=f):
    print("{} {}".format(entry.labels['execution_id'], entry.payload))
```

will output:

```
...
gssssmirx021 Function execution took 20522 ms, finished with status code: 200
gsssn1aibbc5 Function execution took 20022 ms, finished with status code: 200
```

Notice the [substring operator](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#comparison_operators) `(:)` on `textPayload:"Function execution took"`